# Is there possibility of getting additional data from err interface Go?

Tags: go, error-handling

I just starting working with golang and errors handling inside it. I working with gophercloud SDK and the error interface implemented in the way that it is providing all necessary data for me.

Here is my code:

```
vol, err := volumes.Get(client, volumeID).Extract()
if err != nil {

    log.Printf("Error with getting volume from gophercloud/openstack: %s\n", err)
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 404)
    return
}
```

and here is a data of error that I'm seeing in debug mode

[image]

As you can see on the screen there is an actual error code, is there a possibility to extract it from error variable to use in the http.Error() method?

Thank you.

Comment: Please work through https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 ff which explains all this.

Comment: [Half the package is errors](https://godoc.org/github.com/gophercloud/gophercloud). You could use a type switch against your `err` value to any of the types or interfaces, or use the new `errors.As`/`errors.Is` in the [`errors` package](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/).

Comment: Hello, errors in Go can be confusing at the beginning. I suggest to have a look at https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2019/09/11/programming-with-errors.html, https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors and https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully (note that the last link, although full of good advise, is pre Go 1.13 and so doesn't show errors.Is() and errors.As())

Answer (score 1):

You can use `errors.As` (*GoLang 1.13+*):

```
type errorString struct {
    msg  string
    val  string
}

func (e *errorString) Error() string {
    return e.msg
}

func newError(msg, val string) error {
   return &errorString{msg, val}
}

func TestErrorAdditionalInfo(t *testing.T) {
   err := newError("MSG", "SOME_VAL")

   var es *errorString
   if errors.As(err, &es) {
       fmt.Printf("Err[msg: %s; val: %s]\n", es.msg, es.val)
   }
}
```

Comment: unc newError(msg, val string) error`  return `error` type and  in the line `err := newError("MSG", "SOME_VAL")` `err` is `var err error`

Comment: `es` is **ALREADY** an `errorString`, why type assert additionally? Simply use `es`. `fmt.Printf("Err[msg: %s; val: %s]\n",es.msg, es.val)`

Comment: because we do not have access to fields `msg` and `val` from `error`-type

Comment: `es` is not `error` it's `var es *errorString`, and you have `msg` and `val` there